# Is this Russian song from "Chainsaw Man" real?

Tags: chainsaw-man

In chapter 43 of Chainsaw Man manga, Reze sings this song while strangling a man:

> день моего свидания с **джейн**
> все готово
> Утоом мы пойдем вместе а церковь
> Мы будем пить кофе и есть омлеты в кафе
> После того как мы прогуляемся в парке
> Мы пойдем в аквариум и увиде любимых **Джейн**, дельфинов и пингвинов
> Посло обода мы отдохнем
> итак, что мы сделали утром
> Мы будем говорить об этом пока не вспомним
> Мы не вспомним
> И ночью мы будем спать в церкви

I don't know Russian so I used Google Translate:

> the day of my date with **jane**
> all is ready
> Utoom we will go together to the church
> We'll drink coffee and eat omelettes in the cafe
> After we take a walk in the park
> We will go to the aquarium and see **Jane**'s favorite dolphins and penguins
> ...

There are two mentions of джейн (Jane) but I don't recall any Janes from the manga. Fandom Wiki doesn't help either. Denji sounds similar but she wouldn't sing this for Denji as she doesn't have any feelings for him, which makes me wonder.

Does this song actually exist?

Comment: Mistake on line 3. Its not утоом(utoom) it's actually утром(utrom)(in the morning)

Comment: I heard this song while I was watching an film ( I dont remember film name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Russian song does not seem to really exist.**

However, according to some Japanese fans, the most popular theory is that the song resembles [Betty Neels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betty_Neels)' romance novel [*Dearest Mary Jane*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/933264.Dearest_Mary_Jane) (also known as [二人のティータイム](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E4%BA%8C%E4%BA%BA%E3%81%AE%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A0%E2%80%95%E6%81%8B%E4%BA%BA%E3%81%AF%E3%83%89%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC-%E3%83%8F%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AC%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%BB%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A8%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88-%E3%83%99%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3-%E3%83%8B%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%82%BA/dp/4596762481) / *Tea Time for Two* in Japan).

The story is about the protagonist Mary Jane and her sister Felicity both meeting and falling in love with a surgeon, Sir Thomas Latimer.

This coincides with the composition of Reze and Makima's fight for Pochita and Denji's attraction to them. Also, Jane, who runs the cafe, might be Reze, and Felicity, who is blessed with good looks, might be Makima.

---

References (all in Japanese):

- [Michau! - What is Reze's Russian song about? Including the meaning of the lyric (Chainsaw Man)](https://mitaiyomitai.com/manga/post-24134/)
- [Manga Comic Netabare - (Chainsaw Man) Reze singing in Russian became a hot topic! Is it not a merciless lyric? The reason why Reze sings in Russian?](https://manga-comic-netabare.com/archives/19974/%E3%83%81%E3%82%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%AC%E3%82%BC%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B7%E3%82%A2%E8%AA%9E%E6%AD%8C%E3%81%86%E6%AE%8B%E9%85%B7%E6%AD%8C%E8%A9%9E%E7%90%86%E7%94%B1/#i-4)
- [Shonen Create - (Chainsaw Man) Translating Reze's song! Introducing the meaning of the Russian song and its origin](https://www.kurieisha.com/chainsawman-reze-song#index_id3)
- [Twitter - a tweet by @karin5858 on Jan 15, 2020](https://twitter.com/karin5858/status/1217448986027548673)

Answer (score 4):

I'm from Russia and I've never heard of this one, also Google did not bring me any answers, so it doesn't exist. (besides, it is quite intriguing why the author composed a song in Russian)